# Reset EF DBContext after SaveChanges Rollback DbContextTransaction

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext, rollback, savechanges

I use DbContextTransaction in UOW design pattern with EntityFrameWork 6.1, all is ok except Rollback the DBContext after Rollback of transaction
Which I mean is like below :

1. DBContext is on initial sate
2. Create a transaction
3. Do some work:
   **3.1** create childs of the parent entity and save the entity
   **3.2** Call SaveChanges of context
4. Exception is thrown after this
5. Call RollBack of transaction:

Expected: Data is not saved nether in Database nor the DBContext
What happens: Data is not saved in DB **BUT IT STILL EXISTS ALWAYS IN CONTEXT !!**

I tried using the ChangeTracker but all entities states is Unchanged .

So the question: How to rollback the modification in the Context also after calling SaveChanges.

I hope founding help because I pass a lot of time trying many forum's solutions

Answer (score 0):

> How to rollback the modification in the Context also after calling SaveChanges.

You don't.  Just create a new DbContext instance.  The unsaved changes in the DbContext are retained, as you might want to retry SaveChanges after the rollback.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, is it a best practice doing like this ?